# JFormattedTextField with date and time

Tags: java, swing, datetime, actionlistener, jformattedtextfield

I want to get the value of my JFormattedTextField and convert it to string
here is my code for the JFormattedTextField

Here's my code:

```
public void formattedTextField()
    {

            timeAndDate = new JFormattedTextField(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy - HH:mm"));
            timeAndDate.setValue(new Date());
            timeAndDate.setBounds(140,384,145,31);
            add(timeAndDate);
            try{
            contactNo = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter("(+63)9 ##########"));
            contactNo.setBounds(140,216,145,31);
            add(contactNo);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e,"",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
    }
```

I would like to get the contactNo as string too. But I don't know how and what will I put on my actionlistener. When I click the button, the data is to be stored in the database. I use MySQL database
heres my current code of actionListener:

```
public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource()==submitB)
            {
                //validate text
                validation();
                if(validation()){
;
                    // combo box gender
                    String genderText =(String)gender.getSelectedItem();
                    // get the button model selected from the button group
                    ButtonModel selectedModel = group.getSelection();
                    //insert data to database
                    System.out.print("Inserting");
                    GuestsInfo guestInfo = new GuestsInfo(firstName.getText(),lastName.getText(),age.getText(),
                            genderText,address.getText(),"123444","10:00",stay.getText(),"10.00");
                    System.out.print("Successful");
                }
                else{       
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid input","",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
```

i entered "123444" as temporary for contact no. and "10:00" for time and date since i don't know yet how to get the value from JFormattedtextField, and also "10.00" because i need to to compute the balance of the user.
I want to know how can i get the value of JFormattedTextField in string so i can put it on the MySQL.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too vague, what is the real question here? ActionListener to print string, input into a database? You also don't specify what data you would like to print out other then 'contactNo' which is not stated anywhere else and do not state what type of database your using. Please clarify yourself.

Comment: What is the question here?What actually you need to do?save in database or get the contact number?Have you tried something?

Comment: unrelated: don't do manual sizing/locating of components, _ever_ That's the _exclusive_ task of a suitable LayoutManager.

Comment: @kleopatra I just new to java so sorry for the mess code. I'm still practicing and thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy  HH:mm").format(new Date());

timeAndDate = new JFormattedTextField(date);
```

Comment: or use [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)